# Void type not allowed here error while implementing a stack using queues

Tags: data-structures, compiler-errors, stack, queue, void

I am trying to implement a stack using queues. I am using 2 queues for implementation. I am getting an error "Void type not allowed here " in "top=q1.remove()" in pop() function.

What should I modify in this code ?
Thanks in advance.

```
class MyStack {

    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    private Queue<Integer> q1=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private Queue<Integer> q2=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private int top;

    /** Push element x onto stack. */
    public void push(int x) {
        q1.add(x);
        top=x;
    }

    /** Removes the element on top of the stack and returns that element. */
    public void pop() {
        while(q1.size()>1){
            top=q1.remove();
            q2.add(top);
        }
        q1.remove();
        Queue<Integer> temp=q1;
        q1=q2;
        q2=temp;


    }

    /** Get the top element. */
    public int top() {
        return top;
    }

    /** Returns whether the stack is empty. */
    public boolean empty() {
        return q1.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem is you're not checking for empty in pop()

Comment: [The code compiles for me.](https://ideone.com/k0MCAG)